# Intersect of two lines by begin and end points

Tags: python

I have a fairly basic question here. I want to find if two lines on a 1-D plane intersect. I know of two simple ways to solve this, but I wanted to know if Python has a more elegant way to solve this?

Ex:

```
x = [1, 10] # 1 = begin, 10 = end
y = [15, 20]
z = [5, 12]

#Method 1: Works. Is quick. Lots of typing.
def is_intersect_1(a, b):
    bool_check = False
    if a[0] <= b[0] <= a[1] or \
    a[0] <= b[1] <= a[1] or \
    b[0] <= a[0] <= b[1] or \
    b[0] <= a[1] <= b[1]:
        bool_check = True
    return bool_check

is_intersect_1(x,y) # False
is_intersect_1(x,z) # True

#Method 2: Quicker to write. Simpler to read. Uses more memory and is slower.

def is_intersect_2(a, b):
    bool_check = False
    if set(range(a[0], a[1]+1)).intersection(set(range(b[0], b[1])):
        bool_check = True
    return bool_check

is_intersect_2(x,y) # False
is_intersect_2(x,z) # True
```

Comment: Try posting your question on [codereview.SE] instead.

Comment: You should probably post on code review, as @Mast suggested. You could also look at how SymPy does it: http://docs.sympy.org/0.7.0/modules/geometry.html

Comment: Your second fucntion can be simplified to `return set(range(a[0], a[1]+1)).intersection(range(b[0], b[1]))`

Comment: I think the question is a valid python question, as well as one of algorithms. I would certainly be interested to see any other solutions.

Comment: The second approach is (1) far less general [only works for integers] (2) extremely inefficient for large ranges.  There's no real reason to use the second one except for pedagogical reasons.

Comment: Your first function can also be reduced to a single return, your boolean flags are not needed at all

Comment: Do lines include their beginning and end points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although not Python-centric per se, here's an elegant way of solving the problem.
The central idea is that if the two intervals aren't completely disjoint, then they must intersect, so all you have to do is check for that condition.

```
class Interval(object):
    """ Representation of a closed interval from 'a' to 'b'. """
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a, self.b = (a, b) if a < b else (b, a)  # make a min & b max

    def intersects(self, other):
        return self.b >= other.a and self.a <= other.b

    def __str__(self):
        return '[{0.a:>{w}}, {0.b:>{w}}]'.format(self, w=2)

testcases = ((Interval(1,  5), Interval(11, 14)),  #  xxxxx
                                                   #            xxxxx
             (Interval(1,  9), Interval( 7, 15)),  #  xxxxxxxxx
                                                   #        xxxxxxxxx
             (Interval(5,  9), Interval( 1, 15)),  #      xxxxx
                                                   #  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
             (Interval(0, 15), Interval( 5,  9)))  #  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                                                   #      xxxxx

for I1, I2 in testcases:
    print('{} {:^7} intersect with {}'.format(
                            I1, "does" if I1.intersects(I2) else "doesn't", I2))
```

Output:

```
[ 1,  5] doesn't intersect with [11, 14]
[ 1,  9]  does   intersect with [ 7, 15]
[ 5,  9]  does   intersect with [ 1, 15]
[ 0, 15]  does   intersect with [ 5,  9]
```

Comment: One thing that _is_ Pythonesque about this is that `a` and `b` can be instances of any one or two types that are comparable or ordered. I've personally used something similar to this with `datetime.date` objects and it also works with floating point numbers.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't attempted to measure the performance, but I think this is clearer and likely to be faster - it trades the "or", potentially, of two additional "ternary comparisons" for two comparisons (min and max):

```
>>> x = [1,10]
>>> y = [20,15]
>>> z = [5,12]
>>> def intersects (a, b):
...   c = [min (b), max(b)]
...   return (c[0] < a[0] < c[1]) or (c[0] < a[1] < c[1])
... 
>>> intersects (x, y)
False
>>> intersects (x, z)
True
```

a intersects b if either end is within b. In the function, c just assures that we know which end of b is which. It would work equally well swapping the treatment of b for a.

Measuring the performance would require running a suite of all possible permutations of the specification of the second line, and the choice of intersection of either end, or neither.

Edited from here.
I cranked up an ipython notebook to test the performance. The first method in the initial post is in fact faster based on a sample of intervals generated at random in the range -100 to 100. Mine made the comparison in 827 microseconds per loop through the 1000 comparisons versus 527.

Unfortunately, the testing showed that the first method in the post fails.

[59, -35] [89, -9] False

```
f = intersects2
for x in w:
    print (v, x, f(x, v))
```

[59, -35] [89, -9] False

[59, -35] [76, 89] False

Comment: It is actually slower than the OP's first solution

Comment: Asserting it is unconvincing. Reproducible results?

Comment: you are the one who claimed it is faster so you should provide some proof.

Comment: I stated that the OP's first example out performs your code after testing both. It is not an assertion it is a fact derived from actually timing the code.

Comment: OK. You did not state what tests were made. Clearly the time taken would depend on the data set used since python short cuts on the OR operation. In any event, I did perform tests. If I knew how to post an ipython notebook in here, I could show the results AND they would be reproducible by others. In any event, see the edit of my post. The first test was made with only two trial vectors and one of the comparisons failed.

Comment: Just use the timeit magic command from an ipython shell and copy the output to your answer.

Comment: Creating  a list is also adding overhead  `c0, c1 = min(b), max(b)
    return (c0 < a[0] < c1) or (c0 < a[1] < c1)` will be more efficient

Answer (score 0):

This question turned out to be more interesting than I expected. To me, the original solution just looked too complicated. I don't trust complicated, so I tried my own hand at a solution, which was simpler, and easily provably correct. I should have left the comparison at less than or equal, instead of just less than. After playing around to compare the speeds of the two, I accidentally, on a test of only two conditions, found that the original solution was flawed. I also found out that, though my solution - with the correction just mentioned - was slower than the proposed solution.

The proposed solution fails 5 of 24 possible cases. I leave it to the author to correct his function. I have not even tried to determine where his error occurred. But I offer the following function, to be used for testing.

There are tools that test code coverage. This problem and the solutions are interesting in that the coverage to test fully the solution need to be at less than the line level in granularity.

In the following code, pass the proposed function to test_intersection. It will throw an exception if even one of the 24 possible cases fails. My solution, and the modification proposed using a tuple internally, pass all 24. The original solution fails 5 of the cases. After posting this, I realize that there are some additional cases that could be added. ([3,4], [3,7]), ([3,7], [3,7]), ([4,7], [3,7]) as well as the variants in which the "intervals" of the lines are backward.

```
def test_intersection (f):
    assert not f ([1,2], [3,7])
    assert     f ([1,3], [3,7])
    assert     f ([1,4], [3,7])
    assert     f ([4,5], [3,7])
    assert     f ([4,8], [3,7])
    assert     f ([7,9], [3,7])
    assert not f ([8,9], [3,7])
    assert not f ([2,1], [3,7])
    assert     f ([3,1], [3,7])
    assert     f ([4,1], [3,7])
    assert     f ([5,4], [3,7])
    assert     f ([8,4], [3,7])
    assert     f ([9,7], [3,7])
    assert not f ([9,8], [3,7])
    assert not f ([1,2], [7,3])
    assert     f ([1,3], [7,3])
    assert     f ([1,4], [7,3])
    assert     f ([4,5], [7,3])
    assert     f ([4,8], [7,3])
    assert     f ([7,9], [7,3])
    assert not f ([8,9], [7,3])
    assert not f ([2,1], [7,3])
    assert     f ([3,1], [7,3])
    assert     f ([4,1], [7,3])
    assert     f ([5,4], [7,3])
    assert     f ([9,7], [7,3])
    assert not f ([9,8], [7,3])
```